# Cannot install Cygwin on Windows 10

Tags: linux, windows-10, installation, cygwin, url

Trying to install Cgywin on my system I am getting no options at all of download sites

[image: Installation image]

Does anyone know where I can find the download links to put in the boxes? I've looked but I can't see any that work anywhere

Comment: Usually, that list would be populated with the official mirror list. Do you need to use a proxy to access the Internet?

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28673949/cygwin-no-available-download-site/56068181  there are good answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The URLs should populate automatically. If they don't I would suggest disabling any VPNs or alternative network routings you might have running, restarting the machine and re-downloading the file. You should find this resolves the issue.

If you just have a VPN running through a third-party program it may be a case of simply uninstalling it, or even clicking the 'disconnect' button. If you have setup proxies or a VPN in your browser (like Firefox or Internet Explorer or Google Chrome) then you should be able to find the settings with a simple Google search of 'Proxy settings' or 'VPN settings' followed by the name of your browser. Be sure to include the version number for your particular browser, which you should be able to find in the 'About' section. In the version of Chrome I have for example you simply open the menu tab (three horizontal lines in the top right-hand corner) then click 'help' followed by 'About Google Chrome'. Firefox and Internet Explorer should be similar.

Answer (score 2):

Try entering one of these URLs manually:

- `http://cygwin.mirror.constant.com/`
- `http://mirror.devback.com/`
- `http://go-parts.com/`

A far more comprehensive list can be found at https://cygwin.com/mirrors.html.